# Monoids and Num in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monoids

I have been learning Haskell over the past few months and I came across an example of Monoids that has me puzzled.

Given these definitions:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq) 

instance F.Foldable Tree where  
    foldMap f Empty = mempty  
    foldMap f (Node x l r) = F.foldMap f l `mappend`  
                             f x           `mappend`  
                             F.foldMap f r
```

And this Tree:

```
testTree = Node 5  
        (Node 3  
            (Node 1 Empty Empty)  
            (Node 6 Empty Empty)  
        )  
        (Node 9  
            (Node 8 Empty Empty)  
            (Node 10 Empty Empty)  
        )
```

If I run:

```
ghci> F.foldl (+) 0 testTree  
42  
ghci> F.foldl (*) 1 testTree  
64800
```

How does GHCi know what Monoid to use for the mappend when it's folding? Because by default the numbers in the tree are just of the type Num, and we never explicitly said they where of some Monoid such as Sum or Product.

So how does GHCi infer the correct Monoid to use? Or am I totally off at this point?

Example source: http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids

Comment: While it is not implemented in this way, you can pretend that `F.foldl` internally chooses the list monoid, turning the tree into a list, and then folding over that as usual. As long as the tree is a finite one, this mental model should be accurate to describe the actual result.

Comment: Actually the `Sum` or `Product` monoids are not used anywhere here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Short answer**: it is a type constraint in the signature of `foldMap`.

If we look to the source code of `Foldable` (more specifically `foldMap`), we see:

```
class Foldable (t :: * -> *) where
  ...
  foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

So that means that if we declare `Tree` a member of `Foldable` (not that `Tree` has kind `* -> *`), it means that a `foldMap` is defined over that tree, such that: `foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> Tree a -> m`. So this thus means that the *result type* (and the result of the function passed to `foldMap`) `m` must be a `Monoid`.

Haskell is statically typed: after compile time, Haskell knows exactly the types that are passed in an out of every function *instance*. So that means it knows for instance what the output type will be, and thus how to handle it.

Now `Int` is not an instance of `Monoid`. You here use `F.foldl (+) 0 testTree`, so that means that you more or less have constructed an "ad hoc" monoid. This works if we look at the [source code of `foldl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#foldl):

> ```
> foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
> foldl f z t = appEndo (getDual (foldMap (Dual . Endo . flip f) t)) z
> ```

This has a lot of logic surrounding the parameters `f`, `z` and `t`. So let us break that down first.

Let us first take a look at `Dual . Endo . flip f`. This is short for:

```
helper = \x -> Dual (Endo (\y -> f y x))
```

`Dual` and `Endo` are types with each one constructor that takes one parameter. So we wrap the outcome of `f y x` in the `Dual (Endo ...)` constructors.

We will use this as the function of `foldMap`. If our `f` has type `a -> b -> a`, then this function has type `b -> Dual (Endo a)`. So the output type of the function passed to `foldMap` has output type `Dual (Endo a)`. Now if we inspect the source code, we see two intersting things:

> ```
> instance Monoid (Endo a) where
>         mempty = Endo id
>         Endo f `mappend` Endo g = Endo (f . g)
>
> instance Monoid a => Monoid (Dual a) where
>         mempty = Dual mempty
>         Dual x `mappend` Dual y = Dual (y `mappend` x)
> ```

(note that it is `` y `mappend` x ``, not `` x `mappend` y ``).

So what happens here is that the `mempty` that is used in the `foldMap` is `mempty = Dual mempty = Dual (Endo id)`. So a `Dual (Endo ...)` that encapsulates the *identity function*.

Furthermore the `mappend` of two duals comes down to *function composition* of the values in `Endo`. So:

```
mempty = Dual (Endo id)
mappend (Dual (Endo f)) (Dual (Endo g)) = Dual (Endo (g . f))
```

So that means that if we fold over the tree, in case we see an `Empty` (a leaf), we will return `mempty`, and in case we see a `Node x l r`, we will perform the `mappend` as described above. So a "*specialized*" `foldMap` will look like:

```
-- specialized foldMap
foldMap f Empty = Dual (Endo id)  
foldMap f (Node x l r) =  Dual (Endo (c . b . a))
        where Dual (Endo a) = foldMap f l
              Dual (Endo b) = helper x
              Dual (Endo c) = foldMap f l
```

So for every `Node` we make a function composition right-to-left over the the children and item of the node. `a` and `c` can be compositions of the tree as well (since these are recursive calls). In case of a `Leaf`, we do nothing (we return `id`, but the composition over an `id` is a no-op).

So that means that if we have a tree:

```
5
|- 3
|  |- 1
|  `- 6
`- 9
   |- 8
   `- 10
```

This will result in a function:

```
(Dual (Endo ( (\x -> f x 10) .
              (\x -> f x 9) .
              (\x -> f x 8) .
              (\x -> f x 5) .
              (\x -> f x 6) .
              (\x -> f x 3) .
              (\x -> f x 1)
            )
      )
)
```

(omitted the identities, to make it a cleaner). This is the outcome of `getDual (foldMap (Dual . Endo . flip f))`. But now we need to post process this result. With `getDual`, we get the content wrapped in the `Dual` constructor. So now we have:

```
Endo ( (\x -> f x 10) .
       (\x -> f x 9) .
       (\x -> f x 8) .
       (\x -> f x 5) .
       (\x -> f x 6) .
       (\x -> f x 3) .
       (\x -> f x 1)
     )
```

and with `appEndo`, we obtain the function wrapped in `Endo`, so:

```
( (\x -> f x 10) .
  (\x -> f x 9) .
  (\x -> f x 8) .
  (\x -> f x 5) .
  (\x -> f x 6) .
  (\x -> f x 3) .
  (\x -> f x 1)
)
```

and then we apply this to `z` the "initial" value. So that means that we will process the chain starting with `z` (the initial element), and apply it like:

```
f (f (f (f (f (f (f z 1) 3) 6) 5) 8) 9) 10
```

So we have constructed some sort of Monoid, where `mappend` is replaced by `f`, and `mempty` as a no-op (the identity function).

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't need to. `foldl` is translated into `foldr` which translates into `foldMap` over `Endo` which means function composition which means simple nesting of the function *you have supplied*.

Or something. Meaning, `foldl` could be translated into `foldMap` over `Dual . Endo` which composes left-to-right, etc..

*update:* yes, [the docs says](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Foldable):

> Foldable instances are expected to satisfy the following laws:
>
> ```
> foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t ) z
> foldl f z t = appEndo (getDual (foldMap (Dual . Endo . flip f) t)) z  -- << --
> fold = foldMap id
> ```

`Dual (Endo f) <> Dual (Endo g) = Dual (Endo g <> Endo f) = Dual (Endo (g . f))`. So when `appEndo` strikes, the chain of functions that's been built, i.e.

```
    ((+10) . (+9) . (+8) . (+5) . ... . (+1))
```

or equivalent (here, shown for the `(+)` case), is applied to the user-supplied value -- in your case,

```
                                                 0
```

Another thing to notice is that `Endo` and `Dual` are `newtype`s, so all these machinations will be done by compiler, and be gone by run time.

Comment: But at some point the Num's that exist in the nodes need to be some sort of Monoid, or else mappend would throw an exception, would it not?

Comment: Scratch that Endo is a monoid, I have not seen this before though.

Comment: No, they are not. `mappend` works on `Endo f`, for which it is `Endo f <> Endo g = Endo (f . g)`. "Endo" here is just a marker; the important bit is the `f . g`.

Comment: `appEndo` doesn't actually result in anything being applied. It just extracts the monoidally collapsed final function from the `Endo` newtype wrapper. You still have to apply it to something manually, which is what that `z` argument is.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin it's like `($)`. Does it apply its argument function? (no) Do we think of it as application operator? (yes).

Answer (score 4):

There is (implicitly, if not explicitly), a monoid instance for ordinary functions of the form `a -> a`, where `mappend` corresponds to function composition, and `mempty` corresponds to the `id` function.

What is `(+)`? It is a function `(Num a) => a -> a -> a`. If you `foldMap` over your foldable full of numbers with `+`, you turn each one into the partially applied `(+ <some number)`, which is a `a -> a`. Lo and behold, you've found the magic `f` that will turn everything in your foldable into a monoid!

Assuming there was a direct monoid instance for functions, you'd be able to do:

```
foldMap (+) [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

, which would produce an ultimate `(Num a) => a -> a` that you could apply to `0` to get `10`.

There is no such direct instance however, so you need to use the builtin `newtype` wrapper `Endo` and the corresponding unwrapper `appEndo`, which implement monoid for `a -> a` functions. Here's what it looks like:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> (appEndo (foldMap (Endo . (+)) [1, 2, 3, 4])) 0
10
```

Here `Endo .` is just our annoying need to lift plain `a -> a`s so they have their natural `Monoid` instance. After the `foldMap` is done reducing our foldable by turning everything into `a -> a`s and chaining them together with composition, we extract the final `a -> a` using `appEndo`, and finally apply it to `0`.