# Haskell Foldable tree mempty implementation

Tags: haskell, foldable

Hi I need help in understanding this Foldable tree implementation from from [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids)

Consider the following

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as F  

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)  

instance F.Foldable Tree where  
    foldMap f Empty = mempty   
    foldMap f (Node x l r) = F.foldMap f l `mappend`  
                             f x           `mappend`  
                             F.foldMap f r
```

I have difficulty in understanding how in this example, mempty and mappend get their implementation what their types and how they infered from for example the following invokation.

```
F.foldl (+) 0 testTree
```

Thanks

Comment: In essence `foldl` will create an "ad hoc" monoid with `(+)` as the `mappend` here and `0` as the `mempty`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, is there any link with source code explaining how it does it under the hood?

Comment: this might explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47576620/67579

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Amazing :) 5 years ago the same question with the same example.

Comment: Also related (and also about that LYAH example): [*Foldr/Foldl for free when Tree is implementing Foldable foldMap?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23319683/2751851)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the signature of `foldMap`:

```hs
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

See the `Monoid m =>` constraint in there? It means that every time somebody calls `foldMap`, they have to choose a type `m` and provide an instance of `Monoid` for that type.

It's from that instance that `mempty` and `mappend` are coming. Since `foldMap` has been provided an instance of `Monoid`, it can call methods from that instance.

Comment: Thanks, but I am missing the link on how fold create the concrete instance of monoid

Comment: @Boris `foldMap` does not choose the monoid, the caller does. In practice, if you write `foldMap f x :: MyMonoidType`, annotating the call with an explicit monoid type of your choice, Haskell will use the corresponding monoid operations. This is not the only option, for instance the type `MyMonoidType` can often be inferred: `True : foldMap f x` will choose `[Bool]` as the monoid even without an explicit type annotation.